# Merging rasters which overlap using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, distance, overlapping-features

I need to merge two rasters which overlap, both indicate distance values. I need the output of the merge to result in the shorter/lower distance value.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1.

[image]

I work for a security company. What I am trying to achieve is a map of a building with cameras' resolution. Therefore this map must show the cameras and their field of view so that I can know the resolution in pixel/meter of the camera image at every point of the building. My questions are the following:

1. I need the distance from every camera to be linear as shown in the pic, not circular as the Euclidean Distance command does as default
2. I need to keep these output distance rasters limited to the camera field of view, not all around the points
3. I need to cut in the right way every field of view which overlaps each other (see image)

---

I'm starting to figure out many things.
I cannot make the ED on all points at once since. Some part of the map can be covered by only camera A but being closer to camera B which is looking at somewhere else; in this case, the ED would give me back the distance from camera B which I am not interested in. I tried to do Mosaic to New Raster with minimum as the mosaic_metod but it doesn't seems to work very well.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to include details of the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Comment: Also please clarify whether you are actually wanting to merge the polygons or cut them - because you say you want "the polygon or part of the polygon" that gives the smaller distance.  It is unclear what your desired outcome is.  This possibly sounds like you may actually want to re-do your distances as voronoi polygons rather than buffers - depending on what you are trying to achieve? Knowing the desired result will help people give good advice.

Comment: I think maybe Mosaic tool would work with the Mosaic Operator set on Minimum.

Comment: Untested, so I'm making this a comment. 1) Use Euclidean Distance for all camera points. 2) Create 'Field of View' polygons or raster ([this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142855/) may help). 3) Use Extract by mask with the FoV data as the mask to pull values out of the ED raster. If you ran ED on all points at once, you don't need to worry about merging. Otherwise use Mosaic to New Raster with minimum as the mosaic_method. I know you didn't want ED but rather linear from camera points, but a) that isn't true distance and b) I'm not sure how to implement that.