# Buffering Points Directionally

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, buffer

I have about 10,000 points that I want to apply a partial circular buffer to based on an angle,  from -30 to 135°.

A similar question for polygons seems to have been answered ([How to create an oriented buffer using arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/how-to-create-an-oriented-buffer-using-arcpy)), but I cannot make sense of how I would go about implementing that for my scenario.

What steps would I take in ArcMap?

---

Converted points to raster, ran focal statistics with wedge from 210 to 315.

Comment: Do you have a Spatial Analyst license and is using rasters an option? Then you could use the Focal Statistics tool with the Wedge neighborhood. Tell more about the purpose of your analysis (what are you going to do with the buffers? Can they overlap?) if you think the idea could be developed.

Comment: I do have spatial analyst and using rasters is an option. The goal is to apply a buffer to these points based on prevailing wind direction, which will be combined with other layers for modeling habitat suitability for an invasive species. Overlap should not be a problem, because the model will be choosing the max value at a particular cell.

Comment: There is a script (and script tool) on arcscripts that does this called "Generate Polygons from Points, Azimuth and Radius".  Available from: http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16089

Comment: Another related question, with no answer but links to same question in this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142163/for-every-point-create-a-wedge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Spatial Analyst license and using rasters an option, you could use the [Focal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Focal_Statistics/009z000000qs000000/) tool with the Wedge neighborhood. It's probably more appropriate than vectors in your case anyway (overlap of several layers for a suitability analysis).